# Creating own owner_ptr class; how to avoid UB when passing stack or statically allocated addresses?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, c++98

I would like to use own pointer-classes in my code instead of raw pointers to make my code clearer. So I decided to implement a templated `owner_ptr` class which should meet the following requirements:

- It can be initialized with a raw pointer created with the `new` keyword.
- When the owner_ptr object goes out of scope, it must free the allocated memory.
- More than 1 owner_ptr object mustn't own the same allocated object.

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
class owner_ptr
{
    T* ptr;
    bool array;

public:
    owner_ptr() : ptr(NULL) {}
    owner_ptr(T* ptr, bool isArray = false) : ptr(ptr), array(isArray) {}
    owner_ptr(owner_ptr<T>& orig) : ptr(orig.ptr), array(orig.array)
    {
        orig.ptr = NULL;
        /* rvalue loses ownership over the object */
    }

    ~owner_ptr()
    {
        if (ptr != NULL)
        {
            if (!array)
            {
                delete ptr;
            }
            else
            {
                delete[] ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    bool null() { return ptr == NULL; }

    owner_ptr& operator=(owner_ptr<T>& rvalue)
    {
        if (this != &rvalue)
        {
            this->~owner_ptr();
            ptr = rvalue.ptr;
            array = rvalue.array;
            rvalue.ptr = NULL;
            /* rvalue loses ownership again */
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void reset()
    {
        this->~owner_ptr();
        ptr = NULL;
    }

    void addPtr(T* newPtr, bool isArray = false)
    {
        this->~owner_ptr();
        ptr = newPtr;
        array = isArray;
    }

    T& operator*() { return *ptr; }
    const T& operator*() const { return *ptr; }

    T* operator->() { return ptr; }
    const T* operator->() const { return ptr; }

    T& operator[](int i) { return ptr[i]; }
    const T& operator[](int i) const { return ptr[i]; }
};
```

It would be the **user's responsibility** to create a legal `owner_ptr` object like:

```
owner_ptr<int> op1;
op1.addPtr(new int[2], true);
/* OR */
owner_ptr<int> op2(new int);
/* OR */
owner_ptr<int> op3(new int[6], true);
/* OR */
owner_ptr<int> op4(op3);
/* OR */
owner_ptr<int> op5;
op5 = op4;
```

Although I specified it's the user's responsibility and I know that the user can make many mistakes which can cause *undefined behaviour* like:

```
owner_ptr<double> op6;
{
   double something;
   op6.addPtr(&something);
}
std::cout << *op6 << std::endl;
/* causes undefined behaviour */
```

However, is there a way to disable passing statically allocated addresses and the following parameters too?

```
owner_ptr<int> p1(new int);
owner_ptr<int> p2(p1.operator->()); /* <- how to disable this? */
owner_ptr<int> p3(&p1.operator*()); /* <- and this */
/* problem: p1 and p2 (and p3) now own the same object */
```

Any idea that is available in C++98?
Or simpler: is there a way to test with macros if the user passed a pointer to the constructor which was created with `new`? I know it's an ugly idea, but it would be OK for me.

**Please take it into consideration that I'm doing this for learning purposes. Of course, I won't use my own smart pointer classes in production code.**

Comment: Would you also like to disable `&*somePtr`? It's much more likely that you would see someone write that than `somePtr.operator->()`.

Comment: There's no way. And maybe use `unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - I forgot about that! Yes, it would be great.

Comment: Can't be done. My comment was more of a way to point out the futility of what you were trying to do.

Comment: @GergelyTomcsányi Does this have to be C++98?  C++11 has [`std::uique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which is a owner pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know that there are smart pointers in C++11 and I will learn how to use them (in university, next year), but for now, I want to play only with C++98.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - No problem. I was just curoius. However, disabling the `object.operator->()` or `object.operator+()`, etc. syntax is possible?

Comment: Only by not overloading `operator->` and `operator*`. (I assume you meant `*` not `+`)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - I didn't mean any specific operator, I just asked, is it possible to disable using these operators with the `operator` keyword.

Comment: @GergelyTomcsányi I'm afraid you're barking up the wrong tree regarding the operator overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to disable the following syntax?
>
> ```
> owner_ptr<int> p1(new int);
> ```

A simple way I could think of is to hide the

```
owner_ptr(T* ptr, bool isArray = false)
```

constructor from the `public` section and have a `friend` function to create valid instances only

```
template<typename T>
owner_ptr<T> make_owner_ptr(/* T constructor arguments to forward */) {
    return owner_ptr<T>(new T(/* forwarded constructor arguments */));
}
```

---

One problem you have with c++98 though, is how to realize the constructor parameter forwarding. `va_args` isn't a really good solution, since you'll need at least a parameter count sentinel.
Maybe some macro trickery could be used. I'd recommend to have a look on how `boost::shared_ptr` is implemented regarding this.

> ```
> owner_ptr<int> p2(p1.operator->()); /* <- how to disable this? */
> ```

I'm afraid that won't be possible. But avoided in general with my solution from above.

---

> **Of course, I won't use my own smart pointer classes in production code.**

Why not? I did that a lot of times when needed (e.g. to cover pre c++11 ref counting smart pointer classes). I found A. Andrescou's loki library helpful for that.
It's all not that kind of *black magic* it's rumored about. There are some considerations and straightforward restrictions and rules.

Comment: Thanks, it's a great idea! I think, it also prevents the user to create illegal `owner_ptr` objects. I'll try out your idea. Maybe it's better to pass a temporary T object to the function instead of passing the constructor arguments and constructing the allocated object with a copy-constructor. Like: `owner_ptr<int> op1 = make_owner_ptr(int(5));` Maybe the only problem is the time to construct the temporary object which we will drop away later.

Comment: @GergelyTomcsányi _"Maybe it's better to pass a temporary T object to the function instead of passing the constructor arguments"_ Yeah, that sounds like a good idea, it's not that generic and requires to have the pointees a copy constructor, but you have to decide if these restriction is acceptable. I should have mentioned in my answer, that exposing a constructor `owner_ptr(owner_ptr<T>&)` which allows to _"move()"_ may make sense.

Comment: I think, it's not a wise decision to define a copy-constructor for almost every class just because I want to use my own smart pointers with this function and don't want to put so much responisibility on the user. But maybe it's not so costly. I will look it up, which classes must really have a copy-ctr in my code. It would be the best to construct the allocated object without any copy-ctr.

Comment: @GergelyTomcsányi _"It would be the best to construct the allocated object without any copy-ctr."_ But well, you'll have that default constructor required problem again.

Comment: Do you know any macro black magic which I can use to test if the user created the pointer with `new`? Or using your idea, but passing the contructor arguments with some macro?

Comment: @GergelyTomcsányi If so, the latter. As mentioned check boost's implementation, they provide something like c++11's `std::make_unique<>(...)` IIRC.